# Windows Search page based on Text Box field data entered

Tags: c#, sql, windows

I am relatively new to Windows application programming. I have started working with C# and need some assistance.  I have a SQL Database with a Customers table (filled with data) I Have created a Customer Add page (successfully adding new customers and verifying that it is not a redundant customer. I am now trying to create a Customer search page based on TB fields that you can search by First Name, Last Name, Phone Number or Email address, any or all of these fields would query the database table and return the data either to another form or a datagrid below on the same form.  The tutorials that I have found so far keep pulling the data from the database automatically and enter it into the TB fields which is not what I want.
as seen in first image

The SQl Table is as follows

```
customerID    int PK,
trackingID    int FK,
barterID      int FK,
firstName     varchar(50),
lastName      varchar(50),
address1      varchar(75),
address2      varchar(75),
city          varchar(50),
st            varchar(25),
zip           varchar(10),
contactNumber varchar(15),
contactNumber2 varchar(15),
email         varchar(50),
username      varchar(50),
pwd           varchar(50),
customerSince datetime2(7),
lastVisit     datetime2(7),
company       varchar(50)
```

The code I have entered for Query

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Trex
{
    public partial class CustomerSearch : Form
    {
        public CustomerSearch()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void customersBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Validate();
            this.customersBindingSource.EndEdit();
            this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.trexDataSet1);

        }

        private void customersBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Validate();
            this.customersBindingSource.EndEdit();
            this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.trexDataSet1);

        }

        private void customersBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click_2(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Validate();
            this.customersBindingSource.EndEdit();
            this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.trexDataSet1);

        }

        private void CustomerSearch_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'trexDataSet1.customers' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            this.customersTableAdapter.Fill(this.trexDataSet1.customers);

        }

        private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < this.Controls.Count; i++)
            {
                if (this.Controls[i] is TextBox)
                {
                    this.Controls[i].Text = "";
                }
            }
        }

        private void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Hide();
        }

        private void firstNameTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(@"Data Source=VISIONSWS-PC;Initial Catalog=Trex;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=password");
            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;

            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE (firstName = @tbFirstName) and (lastName = @tbLastName)";
            cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;

            sqlConnection1.Open();
            cmd.EndExecuteReader();
            sqlConnection1.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

I only tried with the first 2 text boxes, the other 2 I'm sure can be added easily enough after the correct code has been entered as well as other search criteria. also I guess I can't post images on here yet (not enough rep)

Comment: It's actually a temp password and doesn't matter. It will not actually be the password. Thanks for the advice though

Comment: are you asking about how to write the code so that you can use/call it from different places?

Comment: Yes, I believe I have the correct Query in the line of code just not sure how to implement the code to display the entered text values  to return the correct rows. Example: user enters "John" in First name TB all records within table customers with firstName "John would return all records in the DataGrid below that had the name "John" in the firstName  column.